Name of a 90s UK sci-fi show involving alien invasion
When I was a child, in 1995 or 1996 there was a (kids) TV show which involved aliens disguised as humans that wanted to take over earth. 
One important thing that I remember about the show was that the aliens' eyes sometimes rolled back into their head or turned white. I was terrified of that show.
It was broadcasted either by BBC or ITV.
Does anyone know the name of the show?

It was broadcasted by BBC. The most important detail that I remember was that the aliens eyes sometimes went white and they were all somehow connected.

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Maybe UFO.  It was produced in the early 70s but might have been shown on re-runs.  There's a scene with an eye early in the intro.     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQj_WajKgDY and it was quirky retro-futurism but done with an air of seriousness (and cute lady's buts).  Could have been scary to a kid.

This one is too old, I remember it was a kids TV show

@Hossein What quality made it a kids TV show?

Possibly The Uninvited ?

Steve Blake is a photo journalist who sees a man die in a car crash, only to turn up unharmed the next day. Melissa Gates is one of the few inhabitants of Sweethope who were not 'renewed' when their village fell into the sea five years ago. ...  These two gradually realise something terrible is happening, as strange white-eyed people have synchronised nosebleeds around the world, but of course no-one will believe them. The Uninvited is a rather standard alien takeover conspiracy plot ...from https://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/sf/tv/uninvitd/1r.htm


Was first shown on ITV in 1997 as four 50-minute episodes. It doesn't sound like a kid's TV show though, so may not be the one you're thinking of.

bingo. Thank you!

This sounds like 3rd Rock From the Sun, possibly. Here's its IMDB page:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115082/

No, wasn't a comedy.

Was the show Animated?

No it wasn't...

I've never watched 3rd Rock From the Sun and even I can tell that the OP is not describing 3rd Rock From the Sun.
